# How to test StateSpec.function - how to create a State object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, state

I have a stateful function(in scala) that I am using to check the data of incoming objects.

The function is

```
def updateGeneratedTs(thingId: String,
generatedTsRaw: Option[String],state: State[String]): Option[String]
```

This is then called using

```
StateSpec.function(updateGeneratedTs _)
```

I want to test this but I don't know how to create a State object.  I've tried using StateImpl but this doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using mocks in unit tests?

Comment: no, but I'd prefer to use the real object.  I'd only associate using mocks with third party objects.  Unless this is a more complicated scenario than I undersatnd?

Comment: Looking at this now, is it the case that you have to instantiate State yourself and create your own behaviour?